Azure Function Fails to Authenticate Using Managed Identity (Error 404: Resource Not Found)
I'm trying to configure an Azure Function to access an Azure SQL Database using Managed Identity. I've followed the official steps to enable a system-assigned Managed Identity for my Function App and granted the identity db_datareader permissions on the database.
Here’s the setup:
Azure Function is deployed in a consumption plan.
Managed Identity is enabled at the Function App level.
SQL Server firewall rules allow access for Azure services.
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = "myserver.database.windows.net",
    InitialCatalog = "mydatabase",
    Authentication = SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity
}.ToString());

sqlConnection.AccessToken = credential.GetToken(
    new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" })
).Token;

await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

Azure Function fails with this error:
Error: 404 Resource Not Found: Could not retrieve token from Managed Identity. Ensure the resource is properly assigned.
What I've checked:
Managed Identity is listed under the Function App's Identity settings.
SQL Server logs do not show any attempt to connect.
Verified the Function App has sufficient permissions on the SQL database.

Can you share the query you have used in sql to provide access to your function app

I have modified your code as below to establish a connection to Azure SQL Database using managed identity.
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Azure.Core;

namespace _79261969
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("SqlFunction")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger _logger)
        {
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            var connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = "afreenserver.database.windows.net",
                InitialCatalog = "afreenDB",
            }.ToString();

            using var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            try
            {
                sqlConnection.AccessToken = credential.GetToken(
                    new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" })
                ).Token;

                await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
                _logger.LogInformation("Connection to SQL Database established successfully.");
                return new OkObjectResult("Connected successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error connecting to SQL Database: {ex.Message}");
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
}

Enabled managed identity in consumption function app. Then, I executed the below script in the database.
CREATE USER [managed_identity_name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [managed_identity_name];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [managed_identity_name];
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [managed_identity_name];
GO

This script will grant all the permission to the managed identity.
By doing so, I am able to execute the function successfully.


You can also refer to my answer in this SO-Thread which has a detailed explanation about the same.
